# Mockoon Dockerize command gives error file too old?

Tags: docker, mockoon

So I'm trying to create a proof of consept of getting a Jenkins API from swagger, importing it into mockoon, and then dockerizing it to run as a service in a kubernetes cluster.

I downloaded the JSON from swagger and was able to import into the mockoon desktop application. I then exported it into a file. I downloaded the mockoon cli and then tried to run dockerize but I get the following error:

```
mockoon-cli dockerize -d jenkins-mockoon-api.json -o `./Dockerfile`                                                                                           
    Error: This export file is too old and cannot be run with the CLI
    Please re-export the data using a more recent version of the application
```

I tried re-exporting but no luck. I'm starting to think I'm over complicating it. I just want to be able to deploy a pod with mockoon with that API.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. When Exporting you have to specifically do it as a Mockoon environment JSON, not a Swagger or anything else. Not a very good error message though!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem! Indeed it's not a very good error message and I opened an issue so we improve this: https://github.com/mockoon/cli/issues/35